# Obtaining state variable derivatives from a simulink model

Tags: output, state, simulink, derivative, programmatically-created

I have a simulink process model with a number of control inputs.
I have modeled the process model using a number of susbsytems (m-file block in series and parallel), and the integration is done using an integrator for each subsystem.

I can run this model and get the states and outputs ([Is is possible to programmatically play a Simulink model and measure its states?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356707/is-is-possible-to-programmatically-play-a-simulink-model-and-measure-its-states)), but I would also like to be able to get the *time derivative of the states* sometimes.

For example, if I am running an [optimal control problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control) , I need a function that programmatically returns the state variable derivatives to use as constraints. I would ideally be reusing the same model, but not using the simulink software for integration.

I suppose I could gather the input to every integrator in the model and use that as the derivative, but that is a horrible way to go about it (difficult to maintain, for starters).

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem when running simulink, you may find the following command useful:

```
[sys,x0,str,ts] = model([],[],[],'sizes');
[sys,x0,str,ts] = model([],[],[],'compile');
outputs = model(t,x,u,'outputs');
derivs = model(t,x,u,'derivs');
dstates = model(t,x,u,'update');
model([],[],[],'term');
```

for more details, you can refer to the page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model_cmd.html