# Number of input/output ports with widths for S-function

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

Given a process model in a `C` `S-function` (or a `.mexw` file), how can one determine the number of input/output ports together with their port widths programatically in `Matlab` (in a `.m` script file) without hardcoding them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same technique as in [How can I get signal dimensions in Simulink model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176680/how-can-i-get-signal-dimensions-in-simulink-model/19178551) for the port widths. I believe the `CompiledPortDimensions` property should give you the number of I/O ports. You'll need to compile the model first though.

Comment: What about finding number of ports and widths for a block from the block diagram library?

Comment: The same applies I believe